# Converting For loop to apply function

Tags: r, lapply

My data set looks like this:
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu3qL.png)
I have a function that help me to build an attributes, **att** represents the number of event in the (same year) with the same key and discrepancy on first name main and first name:

```
N=nrow(data)
for(i in 1:N){
data$att[i] = nrow(
  subset(
    data,
    date[i] == date &
      key[i] == key &
      first_name_main[i] != first_name
  )
)}
```

How can I convert/ improve this loop with apply function?

thanks!

Comment: Need a test dataset sumitted AS TEXT. Otherwise  will be nominated for closure. Pictures are for children's books. Text is for programmers.

Comment: Fully concur with 42-. Other reasons against data as an image: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272

Comment: `dput(data)` should be helpful regarding @42 and @r2evans comments. It will recreate the data object for others to create on their computer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sapply` and basically define your loop-body as a function which is evaluated for every row in your dataset:

```
data$att <- sapply(1:nrow(data), function(x){
                                    nrow(subset(data,date == date[x] & 
                                         key == key[x] &
                                         first_name != first_name_main[x]))
                                 })
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @FloSchmo